# I want to assign different Crops to the appropriate Bins

Tags: python, pulp

I've harvested 4 different crops. Have 7 bins of various sizes. I want to assign the crops to the different bins the most efficient way
using pulp. This is what I have so far:

```
Bins = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
BinMax = {"A": 10000,
"B": 10000,
"C": 8000,
"D": 8000,
"E": 6000,
"F": 6000,
"G": 4000}
Crop = ["SOY","WHT", "CAN", "HMP"]
Bushel = {"SOY": 14400,
"WHT": 19200,
"CAN": 8000,
"HMP": 5440}
```

How do I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like a test/assignment question...

Comment: It's an Assignment where I have to write my own code. I want to come up with a crop tracker. I'm not asking for someone to write it for me, I just want to know how.

Comment: The assignment is meant for your own study and growth. It is OK to ask for a hint, but please show what you have tried some approaches and what is the bottleneck in them. Asking for a full solution here is cheating and does not help you to become a better programmer and reduces your chances to pass the final exam.